# Mac Pro starts with folder icon and question mark, HD is empty. How to install Ubuntu?

Tags: mac, unix, mac-pro

I have a Mac Pro with an empty (no existing partitions) 1TB HD connected to it.
I am using a windows USB keyboard and want to install Ubuntu on it.

There is no Mac OS installed or running on this computer. I have no access to another Apple device.

It is not a Macbook.
This is the exactly version: Mac Pro 3.00x/4x1/x1900xt/250/sd/ap

Questions:

- how to **boot the Mac Pro using a USB stick and install Ubuntu on it**?
- can I do it using a simple USB keyboard and Microsoft Wireless mouse?

Comment: People do claim to have got an 08 to boot from USB. Having had two since 2008, I will disagree with them. I have never got an 08 to boot from USB other than with an Apple Hardware Test stick. 09s are easy, 08s… meh. You will also need wired keyboard & mouse to start with.

Comment: @Tetsujin how can I have an Apple Hardware Test stick? Is this any kind of special USB stick with Apple software installed? And if I want to reinstall the Apple software to this device... what do I need? Never did it before.

Comment: The AHT software in just a test suite, nothing else. You can't install from it. To get OS X on the Mac you'd need a retail copy of the Snow Leopard DVD, about $£€ 20 on eBay. I honestly have no idea how you'd get Ubuntu on it without it being bootable from USB, sorry.

Comment: The easiest way to install Linux on it would be from an optical disk. If you can get a Linux live CD, hold 'C' at power on to boot from the CD.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the [tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) from Ubuntu.

This requires access to another running computer (Linux, Windows, Mac). If you don't have one, consider to reinstall macOS with [macOS Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904) installer to prepare the stick. Press <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>opt</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> during a restart to reinstall the macOS that came with your Mac, or the closest version still available.

Comment: Does macOS Recovery works with this old computer? I have a Windows keyboard, is it possible to use this shortcut with a windows keyboard?

Comment: Also, I tried many shortcuts. All I can get is a screen with an folder and a question mark blinking. Any ideas?